# Average number of uniform variates needed for their sum to be $> 1$ should be $\approx e$

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

An interesting [tweet from Fermat's Library](https://twitter.com/fermatslibrary/status/924263998589145090) proves that the average number of random values [0,1] that are needed to `Total` > 1 is about $e$ (2.718...).

I don't get the proof, but I thought that a million trials in *Mathematica* should show something close to $e$ but I keep getting about 2.58 - I was hoping it would be an example of how you could get a clue about the proof by experimenting in *Mathematica*.

I suspect my coding skills are at fault, not the proof...

```
f[n_] := If[Total@RandomReal[1, n] > 1, n, f[n + 1]]
Table[f[2], 1000000] // Mean // N
```

Comment: When `f` is invoked recursively, it doesn't know what random numbers have been chosen and summed so far. For example, try something like `N[Mean[Table[count = 0; sum = 0;
   While[sum <= 1, sum += RandomReal[]; count++]; count, 1000000]]]`

Comment: [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194352) is the CV thread that explains the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mean[Length/@Table[NestWhile[Append[#,RandomReal[]]&,{RandomReal[]},Total@# < 1 &], 1000]]//N
```

Comment: You could also use `Length@NestWhileList[# + RandomReal[] &, RandomReal[], # < 1 &]`. It's more efficient (although in this case it really doesn't matter).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very simple recursive solution.

```
counter[cnt_, total_] /; total > 1. := cnt
counter[cnt_, total_] := counter[cnt + 1, total + RandomReal[]]
Mean[Table[counter[0, 0], 1000000]] // N
```

> `2.71805`

Comment: Far more readable answer, +1

Answer (score 3):

This question has popped up at stats.stackexchange.com ... where alternative algorithms (including solved in mma) are discussed. See:

http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193990/approximate-e-using-monte-carlo-simulation

The code I suggested there is:

```
Mean[Table[Module[{u=RandomReal[], t=1},  While[u<1, u=RandomReal[]+u; t++]; t] , {10^6}]]
```

> {0.208377, 2.71887}

... which is about 50 times faster than the `NestWhile` approach:

```
Mean[ Length /@ 
Table[NestWhile[Append[#, RandomReal[]] &, {RandomReal[]}, 
  Total@# < 1 &], 10^6]] // N // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {9.45841, 2.71663}

And:

```
counter[cnt_, total_] /; total > 1. := cnt
counter[cnt_, total_] := counter[cnt + 1, total + RandomReal[]]
Mean[Table[counter[0, 0], 1000000]] // N // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {5.30918, 2.71847}

**Notes**

1. For an explanation of why the relation holds, see:

   http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194352/
2. For larger samples, the above can be further improved replacing `Table` with `ParallelTable`.

Comment: I would advocate against using `Random` since the underlying method is not necessarily good as an RNG.

Comment: Thanks Daniel  - updated to `RandomReal`